# Removing a column in Pandas without a columns name

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

This question would be very basic but I'm struck in dropping a column without a column name. I imported an excel into pandas and the data looked something like below

```
     A    B
0   24   -10
1   12   -3
2   17    5
3   63    45
```

I tried to get rid of the first column (supposed to be index columns) that has no column name, and wish to have the dataframe with just A and B columns, for instance..

When I ran

```
df.columns
```

I get the below

> Index(['Unnamed: 0', 'A', 'B', dtype='object')

I tried several ways

```
df = pd.read_excel(r"path", index_col = False)
```

and

```
df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
```

and

```
df = df.drop([''], axis=1)
```

the below line display an error

```
self.DATA.drop([""], axis=1, inplace=True)
```

The error for the above line is

> name 'self' is not defined

I tried other possible ways. But nothing seems to work. What is the mistake that I'm making? Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: isn't it simply the index?

Comment: What did you do to `df` between when it looked like the output you shared, and when you ran `df.columns`?

Comment: Or are you saying that it actually looked like the output of: `pd.DataFrame({'Unnamed: 0': {0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 3}, 'A': {0: 24, 1: 12, 2: 17, 3: 63}, 'B': {0: -10, 1: -3, 2: 5, 3: 45}})`

Comment: @BeRT2me This data was actualy extracted from a .mat file into an excel and I believe the conversion from .mat to .xlsx would have created the index column without index name. 'df.columns' actually looks like this: Index(['Unnamed: 0', 'A', 'B', dtype='object')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try

```py
pd.read_excel('tmp.xlsx', index_col=0)

# Or

pd.read_excel('tmp.xlsx', usecols=lambda x: 'Unnamed' not in x)

# Or

pd.read_excel('tmp.xlsx', usecols=['A', 'B'])
```

Comment: This works! I would prefer to use the first two methods while I'm skeptical with the third method considering that the data frame would contain tens or even hundreds of columns.

Answer (score 1):

this should work for the `nth` column in your dataframe `df.drop(columns=df.columns[n], inplace=True)`, if it's the first columns, so `n = 0`.

Answer (score 0):

I worked around as I deliberated on @enke comment and realized that the simple drop function giving the column name (as below) can actually solve the issue of removing the undesired index column

```
df = df.drop(['Unnamed: 0'], axis=1)
```

Answer (score -1):

Try This

```
empty_index = [" " for i in range(len(d["A"]))]
df = pd.DataFrame(d, index = empty_index)
```

here the list is empty spaces..

Comment: can you explain what is the dataframe 'd' and why use column name A?

Comment: d = pd.read_csv("file_name")   and  I've mentioned "A" for getting the column length. So that we get that many blank spaces which we later use those blank spaces as index. We can get that by    df.shape[0]

Comment: just simply use this...     df = pd.read_csv("file_name", index_col = 0)